# openquery giving different results

Tags: sql, odbc

I have 2 similar queries

```
select * 
from openquery(powerschool, 
                'select * 
                 from TEACHERS 
                 where teachernumber is not null 
                   and schoolid=''1050'' 
                   and teacherloginid is not null  
                 order by teachernumber')
```

and

```
SELECT * 
from openquery(powerschool, 
              'SELECT NVL(teachernumber,'''') 
               from TEACHERS 
               where teachernumber is not null 
                 and schoolid=''1050'' 
                 and teacherloginid is not null 
               order by teachernumber')
```

The first one is giving me 182 rows while the second one gives me 83.

What's wrong with the queries?

Answer (score 0):

Second query never would return a null for the teachers table because of the NVL() so it could return more records depending on the data.

basically the " and teacherloginid is not null " never gets hit because you replace the nulls with ""

Comment: Is the WHERE clause not evaluated before the SELECT clause... aka NVL is evalauted after "teachernumber is not null"

Comment: I think someone edited those queries since I commented.  Wasn't the NVL in the where clause originally?

Comment: Even if I remove the NVL and keep the "TeacherNumber is not null" in the where clause the second query gives me 83 rows while the first one returns 182 rows.

Comment: @Jay: not according to revision history

Comment: @gbn How do I see the history?  I can see it was edited, where's the history?

Comment: @Jay: Perhaps it's a reputation thing: "edited yesterday", to the left of "asked yesterday"

Answer (score 0):

Just thoughts...

- Same server? That is, linked server is different in target or credentialss o you are reading a different "TEACHERS" table
- What does running both linked SQL statement actually on the linked server (not locally) give you?